# I want to know how to make a row through the pyspark dataframe fiilter

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark, sum

#### I want to know how to make a row through the pyspark dataframe fiilter.

- example

```
word    ㅣ count  ㅣ rank 
'hello' ㅣ 10     ㅣ 1
'hi'    ㅣ 5      ㅣ 2
'python'ㅣ 3      ㅣ 3
'spark' ㅣ 2      ㅣ 4
'java'  ㅣ 1      ㅣ 5
```

---

result

```
word    ㅣ count ㅣ  rank 
'hello' ㅣ 10    ㅣ 1
'hi'    ㅣ 5     ㅣ 2
'python'ㅣ 3     ㅣ 3
'etc'   ㅣ 3     ㅣ 4
```

From the 4th place in the ranking, I want to make a row by adding count to the etc group. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group By with condition.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy(f.when(f.col('rank') < 4, f.col('word')).otherwise(f.lit('\'etc\'')).alias('word')) \
  .agg(f.sum('count').alias('count'), f.min('rank').alias('rank')) \
  .orderBy('rank').show(10, False)

+--------+-----+----+
|word    |count|rank|
+--------+-----+----+
|'hello' |10   |1   |
|'hi'    |5    |2   |
|'python'|3    |3   |
|'etc'   |3    |4   |
+--------+-----+----+
```